# How to enforce/apply dart linter rules in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

As an example, when using the "extract variable" feature, the variable is declared "var" rather than "final", although the latter is what I usually end up assigning.

The "analysis_options.yaml" file seems to know a linter flag "prefer_final_locals" (and prefer_final_fields).

Is there a way to make the IDE make use of these?

Comment: *Extract Variable* refactoring is powered by the Dart Analysis Server, a tool from the Dart SDK. Could you file this issue in the [Dart SDK issue tracker](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues)?

Comment: @lena There is an open issue already: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38081 however, even though the mentioned commit has been merged, I have no idea how I can make the IDE use it... is this just a matter of time or can I update a specific file on my disk for this?

Comment: you have to wait until the SDK build with the fix is available and upgrade your Dart SDK to this version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `analysis_options.yaml` located in the `flutter` installation directory is NOT used by IDEA as default. In order for these configurations to be applied, the file has to be copied to the root of a dart/flutter project (so, next to the `pubspec.yaml`). The mentioned flags regarding `final`s and much more then get applied without any further action required.